# Load overlay after 'x' seconds if trigger not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched around but am having a hard time finding an answer. I'm still pretty new to all of this and teaching myself. I have some javascript that loads an overlay on click which brings up a form. I also have some javascript that loads the overlay on page load after 10 seconds.

What I want to achieve is linking them together so if the trigger isn't clicked, the overlay loads after 10 seconds. Here is my code for the click.

```
$(function() {
    $('.cta').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').css('display','flex');
        return false;
    }); 

    $('.close-btn').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').hide();
    });     
});
```

Here is my code for the page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    // load overlay if they haven't visited
    if (visited == null) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.overlay').css('display','flex');}, 10000);
        });  
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes');  
    }

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});

$('close-btn').click(function () {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
});
```

I've been testing them separately, not running them both at the same time.

Comment: You can save setTimeout into a variable and cancel it when your trigger is clicked. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: @JayMee probably read again, and thanks for the downvote for my working answer btw.

Comment: @user2415266 - where does he specify what problems he's having?

Comment: @user2415266 - also, your answer deserved the downvote. You have an unnecessary `});` in there. It doesn't work.

Comment: @JayMee how about telling me that instead of downvoting? I oversaw that problem in his code since it wasn't related to the question. How does he not specify what he want's? "What I want to achieve is linking them together so if the trigger isn't clicked, the overlay loads after 10 seconds." To me that's crystal clear.

Comment: A simple syntax error shouldn't be a reason to downvote, just it being a plain wrong answer. And if anyone is considering that anyway, they should be as strict as they claim to be and reverse it after it has been corrected. In any case, in a community people would help each other to try and improve code *together*. A simple comment could and *should* have sufficed for that. Written regardless of who voted on what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

That's how your code would look like with the [clearTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) method I wrote in my comment.

```
var myTimeout;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // set onClick handlers after the page is loaded.
    $('.cta').click(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        $('.overlay').css('display','flex');
        return false;
    }); 

    // Probably choose one of those, you are currently using two
    // onClick handlers for the close-btn apparently:
    $('.close-btn').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').hide();
    }); 
    $('.close-btn').click(function () {
        $('.overlay').fadeOut(200, "linear");
    });

    // check cookie
    var visited = $.cookie("visited")

    // load overlay if they haven't visited
    if (visited == null) {
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.overlay').css('display','flex');}, 10000);
        // }); <= Those were wrong here.
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes');  
    }

    // set cookie
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. I have the click saved as click.js and popup saved as popup.js,  If I saved the variable in the click.js, would the popup.js file be able to read it?  Because I tried putting it all in one file and I can't get it to work, but separately, it works fine.

Comment: Well, you should set onClick handlers when the document is loaded. I edited my code accordingly, that should work in a single script file.